# How to host a local database on macbook, Neo4j

Tags: python, database, neo4j

I have a very basic understanding of networks so I would love some pointers. I am running a project that stores information in a neo4j database. I would like to move the computational work of this project onto a docker image run on an AWS EC2 instance. I am fine with keeping the graph database on my local machine (hosting on EC2 seems too complicated since we have to think about how to persist data after the node is drained).

How would I accomplish this? I understand that I need to forward my database port so that it is accessible to the public. But I don't know how I can accomplish this. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier and convenient to use Neo4j Aura: https://neo4j.com/cloud/aura/.  It is a fully managed graph database on the cloud which means you don't need to manage it compared to EC2.  There are free, professional and enterprise tiers that you can use. Data migration is also easy.  I'm not an endorser of Neo4j Aura. I just tried it out and worked for my needs.